# HAproxy: how to install an intermediate SSL certificate

Tags: ssl-certificate, haproxy

Hi have a problem with SSL and haproxy, i have concatenated the .crt with the private key but if i check SSL state, my site is not trusted and i need install a bundle certificate, i have tried in this way:

```
bind *:443 ssl crt /etc/ssl/mydomain.com.pem ca-file /etc/ssl/mydomain.com-ca.bundle
```

But don't work. HA proxy version 1.5.2

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OK i resolved, i create a .pem file with (in order): certificate, intermediate and private key. It work's

Comment: Thanks! Solved mine as well, had the opposite order!